# How can I identify job postings that might be "ghost jobs?"

Tags: job-search

After seeing [this article about "ghost jobs"](https://clarifycapital.com/job-seekers-beware-of-ghost-jobs-survey), I was wondering if there are ways to identify a job posting that might be for a position the company has no intention of filling. Besides a posting being more than a few months old, are there red flags?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Because correctly applying to job (i.e. not sending the same resume everywhere, but reading about the company and tuning resume/cover letter to the job posting) is extremely time-consuming. If I could avoid spending this time on ghost jobs and focus on real opportunities, that would be great.

Comment: One red flag is when they want a junior person but ask for senior level experience. Or the salary level matches what you could get flipping burgers, but they want years of technical experience.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with trying to spot these types of job listings is that they are often *actual* job listings, having either already been filled or with some intention of attracting and hiring the right candidate but in the future. The obvious answer of "don't apply to low quality job listings" is universally true, not just for avoiding ghost jobs.

The best you can do is cast a broad net when applying so that one ghost job won't impede your job search and keep track of which companies have responded in a reasonable time frame.

Answer (score -2):

> After seeing this article about "ghost jobs", I was wondering if there
> are ways to identify a job posting that might be for a position the
> company has no intention of filling.

The answer was right in the article you linked:

*Anyone looking to avoid applying for ‘ghost jobs' should pay close attention to when they were first posted. Despite 96% of employers claiming they're actively trying to fill an open role quickly, 40% of employers don't expect to fill their active job posts for 2-3 months. In fact, 1 in 10 managers reports having job openings posted for over 6 months. This can happen for many different reasons, but checking to see when a job was posted could help prevent job seekers from applying for ‘ghost jobs. A job that was posted 48 hours ago is more likely to be actively hiring than a job that was posted 3 months ago.*

Comment: Am I bugging or does that paragraph contradict itself?? It says that almost half of job openings are not filled for months, but then it says to avoid a job posting that has been up for months...? What am I missing here.

Comment: @InBedded16, Yes, the paragraph contradicts itself. But the last sentence is correct. "A job that was posted 48 hours ago is more likely to be actively hiring than a job that was posted 3 months ago." There are number of reasons this is true. Also, I would add that you should use your network as well. If you use your network, you could interview for the job before it's posted anywhere.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk true, that's good advice for job searches, although this specific question is about identifying ghost postings and not how to get a job. And I agree the last sentence is correct, but it's an oddly worded way to build up to that.